# How to get context from MainActivity from anywhere and how to access it's functions?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I've just recently started going on about android developing not long after I've got stuck. 
I want to know how can I get MainActivity's context and it's functions globaly (if that's possible)

The only method I've got to work is passing the context as an argument to another classes' constructor. this@MainActivity doesn't work nor does trying to get a function such as MainActivity.getContext() which returns the context.

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        webView1.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView1.webViewClient = Client(this) //Initialize the class

        webView1.loadUrl("https://www.urbs.curitiba.pr.gov.br/mobile/cartao")
    }

    fun getContext(): Context //Not accessible from Client
    {
        return getContext()
    }

}

//Client class
class Client(context: Context): WebViewClient()
{
    val context: Context = context //This works

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String)
    {
        webView1.loadUrl("https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html")
        Toast.makeText(context, "Uau", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        //using this@MainActivity as context is not defined
    }
}
```

It would be great if I could use functions from the mainactivity class but I'm not really familiarized with the language and therefore I can't do so (if it's possible) right now.
This is my first post at stackoverflow and I'm really sorry if it is low quality, I'm not yet familiriazed with the system.

Comment: Why do you need context if it is already gone? You could make a separate class and put all common stuff in it. If you need context for this class, pass it the current activity's context.

Comment: can you post your whole MainActivity and tell which method you want to access in which class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

In your specific case, there's no need to pass an instance of `Context` through the constructor, you can instead access the `WebView`'s [`context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()) property: all `View` subclasses in Android have a reference to a `Context` instance.

```
//Client class
class Client : WebViewClient()
{
    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String)
    {
        webView1.loadUrl("https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html")
        Toast.makeText(view.context, "Uau", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

In general, if you ever need a reference to `Context`, prefer passing it explicitly rather than storing it in global variables - this way you'll be able to prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity.getContext() means there is a public static method called getContext in MainActivity class while there isn't;

about your scenario, you already have passed a MainActivity instance to the Client class so you can just cast it and call getContext() method:

```
class Client(context: Context): WebViewClient()
{
    private val context: MainActivity = context as MainActivity //This works

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String)
    {
        webView1.loadUrl("https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html")
        Toast.makeText(context, "Uau", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        //now its possible
    }
}
```

about accessing a class instances (like your MainActivity) globally, you can always put your instances in a public static variable and access them from everywhere(but implementing this for Android Activity class is a bit tricky )